# I need a rigorous explanation of Shoemake method to sample uniformly from the group of unit quaternions

Tags: algorithms, rotations, uniform-distribution, quaternions

I know and understand the subgroup algorithm to sample from uniform distribution on the
rotation group $SO\left( 3 \right)$, following the following steps:

1. sample $\theta_{1}$ from $\text{Unif}\left[ 0,\, 1 \right]$ and define $R z$, the $3$D rotation about zaxis, of angle $2 \pi \theta_{1}$
2. sample uniformly an element $v$ on the sphere $S^{2}$, following either of the two methods I defined in a SO answer, here: [Uniform sampling arroung a unit sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76208825/uniform-sampling-arroung-a-unit-sphere/76211042#76211042).
3. Define $w=(v+e_3)/||v+e_3||$, where $e_3=[0,0,1]$.
4. return the random rotation $\left( 2 w w^{\top} - I_{3} \right) \cdot R z$.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Uniform_random_sampling)
is given without any mathematical arguments (only a reference to a Shoemake algorithm,
Shoemake, Ken ($1992-01-01$), Kirk, DAVID (ed.), "III.$6$ - UNIFORM RANDOM ROTATIONS", Graphics Gems III, San Francisco: Morgan Kaufmann, pp. $124–132$) a method to sample uniformly
from the group $S^{3}$, of unit quaternions. I know why a random unit quaternion defines a random rotation, but I cannot understand the arguments  given in  the
Shoemake paper, where a unit quaternion defining a rotation of axis $u$, $\left| \left| u \right| \right| = 1$, and angle $\theta$, is $q = \left( \sin\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right) \cdot u,\, \cos\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right) \right)$, while on wikipedia it is $q =\left( \cos\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right), \sin\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right) \cdot u \right)$.

I give below the Shoemake presentation of his method, and I'd be greatful if someone could confirm or infirm its correctness.

**Shoemake notation**:
Let $X_{0}$, $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ be three iid $\text{Unif}\left[ 0,\, 1 \right)$. Compute two uniformly distributed angles, $\theta_{1} = 2 \pi X_{1}$ and $\theta_{2} = 2 \pi X_{2}$, and their sines and cosines, $s_{1},\, c_{1},\, s_{2},\, c_{2}$. Also compute $r_{1} = \sqrt{1 - X_{0}}$ and $r_{2} = \sqrt{X_{0}}$·
The  unit quaternion with components $\left[ s_{1} r_{1},\, c_{1} r_{1},\, s_{2} r_{2},\, c_{2} r_{2} \right]$ is a uniform sample from $S^{3}$.

**Shoemake arguments** that I cannot understand:

"In terms of quaternions, a rotation around z has the form $\left[ 0,\, 0,\, s,\, c \right]$, while a rotation pointing z in an arbitrary direction has the form $\left[ x,\, y,\, 0,\, w \right]$".
(Why the third coordinate is $0$? If the rotation of random axis would be $2 v v^{\top}-I_{3}$, then its rotation angle is π, and a quaternion corresponding to this rotation is in Shoemake notation $\left( \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) v, \cos\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \right) = \left(v,\, 0 \right)$).

Shoemake explains: "If the direction is to be uniformly distributed, $w$ must be
distributed as the square root of a uniform distribution, and $x$ and $y$
must be a uniform plane rotation times $\sqrt{1 - w^{2}}$. The square root is
necessary because the rotated $z$ value should be uniform for a point
uniformly distributed on a sphere. The $z$ value comes out
to be $2 w^{2} - 1$; substituting $w = \sqrt{X_{0}}$  gives $2 X_{0} - 1$, a uniform deviate
between $-1$ and $+1$, as required. The product of the $z$ placement with
the z rotation is $\left[ c x + s y,\, -s x + c y,\, s w, c w \right]$, which is just one step
away from the final code. We know, since this should give points uni-
formly distributed on a hypersphere, that all components have the same
kind of distribution. In particular, the first two components are the
product of two uniform plane rotations times a magnitude of $\sqrt{1 - X_{0}}$,
which can be reduced to a single plane rotation of the correct magnitude,
like the last two components. The result is the code stated".

Comment: [You should use MathJax (an editor for formulas) with $\LaTeX$ here on Math.SE.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) To a certain extent, this is required on Math.SE, as it makes longer and more complex formulas easier to read and normalizes many symbols. You would also have advantages, e.g. you would no longer have to copy each special symbol individually from somewhere, which saves a lot of work.

Comment: OK, thank you [Kevin Dietrich](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1103878/kevin-dietrich)!

Comment: Formula (5) in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372058/volume-of-su2-and-haar-integral/4372878#4372878) shows you how the Haar measure on $SU(2)\cong S^3$ looks like. Hope this helps. In the worst case I would compare it in a Monte Carlo simulation with Shoemake's algorithm.

Comment: I know the Haar measure on $S^3$ from another reference, and a different parameterization of this hypersphere, but it cannot explain the above Shoemake  approach.

Comment: Neither can I, nor do I have an incentive to do so. As I said: MC should show if Shoemake does what we think it should.